# How to synchronize threads between methods?

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety

I'm creating a queue with 10 items (at the BeforeClass), then i'm using 10 threads (using the @Test TestNG annotation with threads) to read the values from the queue. im using a while loop to make sure i'm not trying to poll values from empty queue.
however, due to syncronization issue the while is asking for the state of the queue right before other thread is polling value and clear it, hence i'm getting null instead of stop polling from the queue.
how can I sync between while loop to the queue?

```
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import java.util.Queue;
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentLinkedDeque;

public class LinkedConcurrentQueue {
    Queue<String> queue;

    @Test
    public void testA(){
        queue = new ConcurrentLinkedDeque<String> ();
        for(int i = 0; i<10; i++ ){
            queue.add(String.valueOf(i));
        }
    }

    @Test(enabled = true, threadPoolSize = 10, invocationCount = 10,  timeOut = 100000)
    public void testB() throws InterruptedException {
        while(!queue.isEmpty()) {
            Thread.sleep(20);
            System.out.println(queue.poll ( ));
        }
    }
}
```

the output in this case is:

```
1
0
3
4
2
8
7
6
5
9
null
null
null
null
null
```

Comment: Your issue is that you sleep between checking and taking. Just because cake was in the fridge when you checked it in the evening, doesn't mean that no one will touch it at night while you're sleeping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to sync (because you're using a concurrent queue), but you do need to change the loop a bit:

```
while (true) {
    String el = queue.poll();
    if (el == null)
        break; // no more elements
    Thread.sleep(20);
    System.out.println(el);
}
```

Comment: Well, the original had it, and I'm guessing it's meant to be a placeholder for "do some work with el"..